# SensorManager.getOrientation gives very unstable results

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm getting my phone orientation with help of

```
SensorManager.getOrientation
```

but the results are very unstable, something like +-8 degrees, is there some good way fo filtering the results?

this is how I get the values:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {
        switch (event.sensor.getType ()){
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                aValues = event.values.clone();
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                mValues = event.values.clone();
                break;
        }
        float[] R = new float[16];
        float[] orientationValues = new float[3];

        if( aValues == null || mValues == null )
            return;

        if( !SensorManager.getRotationMatrix (R, null, aValues, mValues) )
            return;

        float[] outR = new float[16];
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, outR);

        SensorManager.getOrientation (outR, orientationValues);

        orientationValues[0] = (float)Math.toDegrees (orientationValues[0]);
        orientationValues[1] = (float)Math.toDegrees (orientationValues[1]); 
        orientationValues[2] = (float)Math.toDegrees (orientationValues[2]);
    }
```

Comment: You may use System.arraycopy instead of event.values.clone() to gain in performance. Here you're always creating new objects, which is quite costly.

Answer (score 0):

Just buffer the values by calculating the average (there are many different calculation possibilities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Types ). Also consider that the more you buffer the slower the app will react to changes!

Comment: Simple avarage doesn't give good results - I'm trying to think of some more complex filtering, but maybe somebody already has a good method for this? I also don't understand, why `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` is deprecated - it was giving vary stable results.

Comment: If you want to you can try my AR framework and read how i did the buffering (start here: http://code.google.com/p/droidar/source/browse/trunk/droidar/DroidAR/src/actions/ActionWithSensorProcessing.java and this http://code.google.com/p/droidar/source/browse/trunk/droidar/DroidAR/src/actions/ActionRotateCameraBuffered.java ) I am first using some low pass filters on the raw sensordata and then a custom buffering function (read the java doc of http://code.google.com/p/droidar/source/browse/trunk/droidar/DroidAR/src/actions/algos/BufferAlgo1.java )